# Destructuring records in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm learning Scheme, coming from a C/C++ background. I'm quite used to putting related values together into structs, and I've found Scheme's records work quite well for this.

If find myself doing this quite often to avoid visual noise in function bodies:

```
(define (f pt z)
  (let*
    ((x (point-x pt))
     (y (point-y pt))
     (d (* x y z)))
   ...)
```

Where `pt` is a `point` record. Is there a shorter way to bind/destructure the fields of a record? Ideally this would work inside a `let` binding, but I can't figure out a way to write a macro that would accomplish this, or if that's even possible.

Comment: What kind of Scheme are we talking?

Comment: You've definitely entered one of the areas where it's important to mention which scheme you're using; this is an area where different Scheme variants differ widely.

Comment: I'm using Chez scheme, but I'm trying to stick to R6RS because I'm trying not to commit to any particular variant at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using chez scheme, I suggest the port of Alex Shinn's match here: https://github.com/fedeinthemix/chez-matchable .  You can match against chez's r6rs records (amongst many other things) with it.

Answer (score 4):

In Racket, we can use [`match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) to destructure the fields of a record. It's debatable if this is a nicer way to do it...

```
(define (f pt z)
  (match pt
    [(point x y)
     (let ([d (* x y z)])
       ...)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got better at Scheme macros since I asked this question, and I'm currently using this macro:

```
(define-syntax derecord
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ record ([name record-accessor] ...) body-forms ...)
       (let ([name (record-accessor record)] ...)
     body-forms ...))))
```

Which gives syntax like this:

```
(derecord my-rec ([x my-rec-x] [y my-rec-y])
    (* x y))
```

It's only slightly nicer than doing it manually in let, but I thought I'd post it for any other beginners like me.